# How do get SQLiteDatabase in GreenDao 3

Tags: android, orm, greendao

Since the update to greenDao 3,  statements like those do not work anymore:

```
getDatabase().insert(TABLENAME, null, values);
getDatabase().delete(...);
getDatabase().update(...);
```

The getDatabase() is a greenDao interface which doesn't have insert, delete and update methods. Thus, it gives me compile time errors. Anybody solved the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class you are getting back is [org.greenrobot.greendao.database.Database](http://greenrobot.org/files/greendao/javadoc/3.1/org/greenrobot/greendao/database/Database.html), which is a database abstraction meant only for greenDAO. You have two options:

1. You hold the reference to the original SQLiteDatabase and pass it to greenDAO during initialization.
2. The Database abstraction class has a method [getRawDatabase](http://greenrobot.org/files/greendao/javadoc/3.1/org/greenrobot/greendao/database/Database.html#getRawDatabase--), which returns the underlying SQLiteDatabase. If you are not using encryption, it will be always android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase. You have to do a cast.

Comment: that means everytime when auto generating the Content Providers I will have to change this??